# How to sort all columns together of a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data.frame:

```
   X65L X65L.1 X65L.2   X67L X67L.1 X65L.3
1  0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
2  0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0065
3  0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
4  0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0065
5  0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
6  0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0065
7  0.0067 0.0084 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071
8  0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0084
9  0.0067 0.0084 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0067
10 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0084
11 0.0067 0.0084 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0067
12 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0071
```

I want to sort all the columns together ad save them to the same data.frame as:

```
      X65L     X65L.1    X65L.2     X67L     X67L.1    X65L.3
1    0.0065    0.0065    0.0065    0.0067    0.0067    0.0065
2    0.0065    0.0065    0.0065    0.0067    0.0067    0.0065
3    0.0065    0.0065    0.0065    0.0067    0.0067    0.0065
4    0.0065    0.0067    0.0065    0.0067    0.0067    0.0065
5    0.0065    0.0067    0.0065    0.0067    0.0067    0.0065
6    0.0065    0.0067    0.0065    0.0067    0.0067    0.0065
7    0.0067    0.0071    0.0067    0.0067    0.0071    0.0067
8    0.0067    0.0071    0.0067    0.0067    0.0071    0.0067
9    0.0067    0.0071    0.0067    0.0067    0.0071    0.0071
10   0.0067    0.0084    0.0067    0.0067    0.0084    0.0071
11   0.0067    0.0084    0.0067    0.0067    0.0084    0.0084
12   0.0067    0.0084    0.0067    0.0067    0.0084    0.0084
```

I have tried the order() function as suggested in previous questions but none of them sort all the columns together:

```
 for (cn in colnames(a2)) {
+     print(a2[order(a2[[cn]]),])
+ }
```

The above-stated command orders the columns one by one but none of them orders all the columns together.

I have also tried:

```
 for (cn in colnames(a2)) {
+     print(a2[order(a2$cn),])
+ }
```

but it gives a2$cn as NULL

As asked by bttomio, here is the dput:

```
structure(list(X65L = c(0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 
0.0065, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067), X65L.1 = c(0.0065, 
0.0067, 0.0065, 0.0067, 0.0065, 0.0067, 0.0084, 0.0071, 0.0084, 
0.0071, 0.0084, 0.0071), X65L.2 = c(0.0065, 0.0067, 0.0065, 0.0067, 
0.0065, 0.0067, 0.0065, 0.0067, 0.0065, 0.0067, 0.0065, 0.0067
), X67L = c(0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 
0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067, 0.0067), X67L.1 = c(0.0067, 0.0071, 
0.0067, 0.0071, 0.0067, 0.0071, 0.0067, 0.0084, 0.0067, 0.0084, 
0.0067, 0.0084), X65L.3 = c(0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 0.0065, 
0.0065, 0.0071, 0.0084, 0.0067, 0.0084, 0.0067, 0.0071)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
12L))
```

Comment: Could you please provide us a `dput` of your data? Thanks

Comment: Is there any needs to preserve the rows?

Comment: There is no need to preserve the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `apply` function with `sort`
to sort each column independently of the other

```
# if you want to sort all colums together

df_sorted <- apply(df, 2, sort, decreasing=F)
```

[image]

Comment: Only sorts two columns

Comment: X65L X65L.1 X65L.2   X67L X67L.1 X65L.3
1  0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
3  0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
5  0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
2  0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0065
4  0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0065
6  0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0065
12 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0071
8  0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0084
10 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0084
9  0.0067 0.0084 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0067
11 0.0067 0.0084 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0067
7  0.0067 0.0084 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071

Comment: The new solution works perfectly fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), sort, decreasing = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
> list2DF(Map(sort, df))
     X65L X65L.1 X65L.2   X67L X67L.1 X65L.3
1  0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
2  0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
3  0.0065 0.0065 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
4  0.0065 0.0067 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
5  0.0065 0.0067 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
6  0.0065 0.0067 0.0065 0.0067 0.0067 0.0065
7  0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067
8  0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0067
9  0.0067 0.0071 0.0067 0.0067 0.0071 0.0071
10 0.0067 0.0084 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0071
11 0.0067 0.0084 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0084
12 0.0067 0.0084 0.0067 0.0067 0.0084 0.0084
```